# makefile have a generic target that is also the default target

Tags: makefile

So I have a makefile rule like this:

```
%:
   @$(MAKE) -C ../makefile $* \
   .. do load of other stuff ..
```

This is so that I can have many makefile subprojects call a generic makefile. And this works.

If I type `make build` then the makefile in ../makefile gets called with target `build`.

The only issue I have is that I can't just call `make` - i.e. there is no default target and so I get the error:

`make: *** No targets. Stop.`

How can I add a default target in that just calls the makefile in ../makefile folder with no parameters? I don't want to just add a second rule that is a copy of the first rule because I don't want to duplicate the "do load of other stuff" part.

Comment: Have you tried setting a default target? `.DEFAULT_GOAL = build`

Comment: @shawnhcorey no, and when I did it worked!!. Thanks dude :). Please add as an answer and I will mark it up. Also - I assume this is some sort of built in makefile thingy?

Comment: Just to provide a [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eDEFAULT_005fGOAL-_0028define-default-goal_0029).

Comment: @G.M. thanks for that ref : )

Comment: You can also add a rule with no commands, like `build:`

Comment: I'm not sure if `.DEFAULT_GOAL` is available in all makes or just GNU make.